# Documentation Pop Ups

Tags: python, pycharm

How can I configure Pycharm such that I always have the documentation pop up every time I hover over a method or an class?

For example in eclipse:
   If I hover the cursor over a c++ function or a class, I can see the documentation for the same in a small pop up window.

Is there some plugin or setting in Pycharm where I can enable the same?

PS: I know PyCharm already has F1 button that can do the same, I was just looking for a hover alternative as I am used to the eclipse way of doing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature is called "Quick Documentation" and the default shortcut for this is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> or <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>MOUSE BUTTON 2</kbd>.

As far as I know, there is no way to enable it on-hover (personally, I found this very annoying in Eclipse).

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness, in current versions of PyCharm (in the years 2016+), quick documentation is available on hover and can be configured in *Preferences > Editor > General > Other*

[image: PyCharm Quick Documentation on hover]